# Is it possible to configure Azure Web site SSL protocols & ciphers

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I want to be able to disable the TLS 1.0 protocol and the RC4 cipher on an Azure website (or Web App) and I can't figure out if it's possible or not. (**edit**: I am aware that SSL 3.0 is disabled by default on Azure websites but I specifically want to disable TLS 1.0)

I know what registry settings to update but the problem of course is that I don't have access to the OS.

There's the [NWebsec startup](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NWebsec.AzureStartupTasks/) tasks that allow you to configure web roles (or cloud service) but my understanding is that this solution does not apply to web apps.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Vote here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/11158626-disable-tls1-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update Jan 2017**

Microsoft have completed a feature whereby TLS1.0 can be disabled via App Service Environment configuration. It's possible to set your own ciphers through the [Azure resource manager](https://resources.azure.com) or change the cipher suite order.

Details are available on the [Custom configuration settings for App Service Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-custom-settings) page.

*Original answer:*

The original answer was that it is not possible to configure anything in the Registry or SSL settings in Azure web apps.

Microsoft are aware of PCI compliance changes and will update the host machines that the web apps run on in their own time frame. They announced in January 2015 that they would starting making updates on 18th July 2015 that would result in an A grade for TLS/SSL endpoints for Auzre web apps on sites like http://ssllabs.com

It's likely that this will be an on-going issue as computing power increases and more vulnerabilities are discovered and hosted  web apps must rely on Microsoft to keep their servers patched and up-to-date in a timely manner.

This link has some more background information on the changes Microsoft are making: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/50f1ab33-c22a-4629-951e-b7510f6b2cbe/upgrading-tlsssl-cryptography-for-azure-web-apps?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

And this link also tracks the feature request that asks MS to disable insecure ciphers in Web apps:
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/7091994-disable-insecure-ciphers-in-azure-websites?page=2&per_page=20

If registry access and specific control of these settings is a requirement, the Azure options are Cloud Service WebRoles or IAAs VMs.

Vote to [get MS to disable TLS 1.0](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/11158626-disable-tls1-0)